# Rearranging the car model letters on the rear of my car

Tags: custom, appearance

Weird question. I'd like to customize the model name on the rear of my car by switching the letters around.

1) Is this legal in the US? Would the police be annoyed if they had to call in a "Loft Gig" instead of a Golf GTI?
2) What adhesive should I use?

Comment: Golf Git would be better...

Answer (score 1):

The only stuff on a car that you are not allowed to remove are safety decals such as [CNG or electric/hybrid badges](https://www.nhtsa.gov/staticfiles/rulemaking/pdf/cafe/FedRegister-Alt_Fuels_2014-02957.pdf). The car must be clearly marked for rescue and service personnel. Don't want to accidentally kill any firefighters after an accident. (This used to be a big problem because hybrids have high voltage)

Other than that any signage can be changed to whatever.

A quality foam double stick tape will do you. You will probably end up covering the back of letters with it and then trim it with a sharp razor blade around the letters.

3M makes some awesome stuff called Adhesive Primer that if applied to the car and letters before the tape will make it hold so much better. I've installed lots of ground effects (factory accesory) this way.

Comment: While I'm not saying you're wrong about the Hybrid signage on the car, do you have any links which corroborates this?

Comment: For safety, that does sound sensible... trucks carrying chemicals have to display signs / codes defining the loads carried for that reason.

Comment: @Paulster, required by NHTSA in US for electric, CNG and other alternate fuel vehicles: https://www.nhtsa.gov/staticfiles/rulemaking/pdf/cafe/FedRegister-Alt_Fuels_2014-02957.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is generally legal and accepted in the US.  The police typically know makes and models of vehicles in spite of emblems displayed.